# How to make rounded percentages add up to 100% in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0

I want to know the percentage increase in the price being rounded off, I have 3 textboxes in winforms : 
 txtCost_Price, SalesPrice, and txtMarkup.
value "txtCost_Price" is = 52500
and the value of "SalesPrice" is = 54300
result of "txtMarkup" = 3.42857142857143
how to make percentage result from txtMarkup not have multiple numbers after comma? I use Indonesian currency.

```
double CostPrice; double results, SalesPrice;

CostPrice = Convert.ToInt32(C_1_1_txtCost_Price.Text); 
SalesPrice = Convert.ToInt32(C_1_3_SalesPrice.Text); 
results = (SalesPrice - CostPrice) / CostPrice * 100;
 
C_1_2_txtMarkup.Text = Convert.ToString(results);
```

Comment: Pick N-1 of the items and add them up, make the other item the result of `100-the_sum`. For example "I'm doing `a+b+c+d` and it's 99.99 - how can I make it 100?" - "Do `d = 100 - a - b - c`"

Comment: I've removed your C# tags down to the C# 2.0 one, since that's the lowest version that apparently pertains to your code. I'd suggest updating to a newer version of C# if possible (we're up to 11 in preview now). Using a version of the language that's 17 years old can severely limit the syntax you can use, and many tutorials, etc. you might follow will probably contain syntax that won't work for you.

Comment: You shouldn't be rounding off and then adding up. You should round off only for display purposes but keep the full value in a numeric variable. You can then add numeric variables to get 100%.

Comment: @user18387401 That's not necessarily strictly true. You could still end up with a not-100% sum. Plus OP's code is entirely integer based, so the maths won't work right anyway, since 9/10 is still 0 with integer division.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar, actually, the OP isn't using integer division. They are converting input to `int` but then assigning the values to `double` variables, so the division is of a `double` by a `double`. If that weren't the case then they wouldn't get `3.42857142857143` in the first place.

Comment: @user18387401 Ah, right you are. I missed that. Though this will only work then if the values they input are whole, which is probably an issue in itself.

Comment: @Caius Jard Aahh.. I didn't even think about it, thanks for the explanation..
This should be a simple calculation, but I'm still learning and not thinking about what you just said.

Comment: @user18387401 Anyway, here's a proof on the "add up to 100" issue I mentioned: https://rextester.com/SNZHI17508

Comment: @ DiplomacyNotWar do you also have any suggestions for me so i can solve this ?

Comment: @RIDWAN Caius Jard's solution is the best way to go about it in my opinion.

Comment: @ DiplomacyNotWar  Ah, yaapp.. I thought so too.. that's the right solution.
thanks everyone, you guys are amazing..